# derivation of partition function in conditional random fields

Tags: machine-learning, graphical-model, bayesian-network, conditional-random-field, markov-random-field

When reading the paper of [Efficient piecewise training of deep structured models for semantic segmentation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01013.pdf), I am confused about the derivation in CRF training (section 6). In specific, I do not know how to get the gradient of partition function Z. What's the definition of Z, and how to derive its gradient as shown in the following images.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Z(\bf{x}; {\bf \theta})$ is the *conditional partition function*:
$$Z({\bf x}; {\bf \theta})=\sum_{{\bf y}\in\mathcal{Y}} \exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]$$

It is simply the proportionality constant (conditioned on ${\bf x}$) to ensure that the total probability over all ${\bf y}$ correctly adds up to $1$:
$$P({\bf y}|{\bf x};{\bf \theta}) \propto \exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]$$
$$P({\bf y}|{\bf x};{\bf \theta}) = \frac{\exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]}{Z({\bf x}; {\bf \theta})}$$
Computing the gradient of $\log Z$ uses the chain rule and the derivatives for $\log f(x)$ (i.e. $\frac{1}{f(x)}f'(x)$), $\exp$, and addition.  Since we end up summing over $\mathcal{Y}$ twice, we use $\bf y$ and $\bf y'$ to distinguish the two:

$$
\nabla_{\bf \theta} \log Z({\bf x}; {\bf \theta}) = \nabla_{\bf \theta} \log \sum_{{\bf y}\in\mathcal{Y}} \exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]
\\ = \frac{1}{\sum_{{\bf y'}\in\mathcal{Y}} \exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]}\nabla_{\bf \theta} \sum_{{\bf y}\in\mathcal{Y}} \exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]
\\ = \frac{1}{\sum_{{\bf y'}\in\mathcal{Y}} \exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]}\sum_{{\bf y}\in\mathcal{Y}} \exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right] \nabla \left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]
\\ = \sum_{{\bf y}\in\mathcal{Y}} \frac{\exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]}{\sum_{{\bf y'}\in\mathcal{Y}} \exp\left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]}  \nabla \left[-E({\bf y}, {\bf x};{\bf \theta})\right]$$

Here is an example of [a paper](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/aistats/fullpapers/234.pdf) that uses the term *conditional partition function* (albeit in the continuous setting).